# Skipping frames in OnPaint Handler using Timer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, game-engine, gdi+

I am creating a game where animations are created using the OnPaint handler and a timer. The application is using a physics system which is producing different results given the same inputs. I suspect this issue is being caused by skipped frames, but I can't pinpoint why this is happening.

Each time OnPaint is called, I calculate how long it has been since I last drew the screen. I then update the objects in the game based on this amount of time. Here is what my OnPaint function looks like:

```
// Frame duration in milliseconds
const int FrameDuration = 20;

void CChildView::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC paintDC(this);     // device context for painting
    CDoubleBufferDC dc(&paintDC); // device context for painting
    Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);    // Create GDI+ graphics context
    graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
    mGame.OnDraw(&graphics);

    if (mFirstDraw)
    {
        mFirstDraw = false;
        SetTimer(1, FrameDuration, nullptr);

        /*
         * Initialize the elapsed time system
         */
        LARGE_INTEGER time, freq;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

        mLastTime = time.QuadPart;
        mTimeFreq = double(freq.QuadPart);
    }

    /*
     * Compute the elapsed time since the last draw
     */
    LARGE_INTEGER time;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
    long long diff = time.QuadPart - mLastTime;
    double elapsed = double(diff) / mTimeFreq;
    mLastTime = time.QuadPart;

    mGame.Update(elapsed);
}
```

My OnTimer handler simply calls invalidate.

```
void CChildView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    Invalidate();
    CWnd::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

I'm not sure why I would be skipping frames here. I'm also not 100% sure I am, but based on the behavior I noticed I think that's where my issue lies.

Comment: _producing different results_ How so? Since your frame duration is different every time I'd expect some variation in how things run.

Comment: For instance, I have circles colliding with each other in animations. If they're moving fast, sometimes they'll move through each other without the collision happening. I think this is happening because the update isn't happening quickly enough, and by the time it does, the circles are no longer colliding.

Is there a better way to do animations where frames have a consistent time between them?

Comment: One.  You should  use a drawing back buffer.  Two.  Your OnPaint function should limit itself to pasting the buffer to the screen DC. Three: In OnTimer(), call mGame.Update(), then force painting by calling RedrawWindow() with the RDW_UPDATENOW flag.   One big change: mGame.Updfate should accept a DC as a parameter to paint on.

Comment: I include DoubleBufferDC.h in ChildView.cpp. Doesn't that make it so I'm using a back buffer? What exactly do you mean OnPaint should limit itself to pasting the buffer on the screen DC?  Also, I'm confused about what you mean in your third point. I tried doing this and I couldn't pass into RDW_UPDATENOW into RedrawWindow. I tried udating the game in OnTime and using Invalidate, but the game was super laggy. I updated the post to show how I'm drawing the game. mGame. Update isn't used to draw the game, OnDraw is, where I pass it a Graphics object to paint on.